# hadoop java.io.IOException: while running namenode -format on OSX

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, java-io

I am getting following error while formatting namenode, I have tried using sudo su as mentioned in some other stack overflow solutions but i am still getting this error,please assist.

```
14/01/16 16:10:41 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map INodeMap
14/01/16 16:10:41 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
14/01/16 16:10:41 INFO util.GSet: 1.0% max memory = 889 MB
14/01/16 16:10:41 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^20 = 1048576 entries
14/01/16 16:10:41 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
14/01/16 16:10:41 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
14/01/16 16:10:41 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
14/01/16 16:10:41 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
14/01/16 16:10:41 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is enabled
14/01/16 16:10:41 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
14/01/16 16:10:41 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map Namenode Retry Cache
14/01/16 16:10:41 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
14/01/16 16:10:41 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory = 889 MB
14/01/16 16:10:41 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
14/01/16 16:10:41 FATAL namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory /Users/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hdfs/namenode/current
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:544)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:837)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1320)
14/01/16 16:10:41 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
14/01/16 16:10:41 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode
```

I just tried creating directory `/Users/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hdfs/namenode/current`but i found out that bin directory has file named `hdfs`so its not allowing me to create a directory named hdfs in bin directory so not sure if I should over write this `hdfs` file or copy it to other location?

Answer (score 0):

If the directory /Users/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hdfs/namenode/current doesn't exist, you can't create a file there, so make sure you create the directory first.

Ensure you that you have read and execute access to all child directories as well: `chmod o+x /Users/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hdfs/namenode/current`

Check if hadoop runs under a different username. To find this you can use this command from the command line: `ps aux | grep hadoop`

Comment: I think i just found out the problem but i still have no solution Let me edit the post and mention what is wrong